# Which phone can I buy now to be sure ubuntu 13.04 will work on it?

Tags: 13.04

Which phone can I buy now to be sure ubuntu 13.04 will work on it? will it be prepared for LTE?

Comment: The Nokia 1100 is Ubuntu certified...

Comment: This question needs to be about **14.04**, and it too early to ask ..

Comment: @RolandiXor Do you mean, certified to connect to Ubuntu? or is that a joke? I doubt Ubuntu touch would run on a machine twice as powerful as that phone.

Comment: @NoBugs I can't believe you had to ask ;)
Of course it is a joke :)